# datagridview with bindinglist and new row issue

Tags: c#, .net, list, binding, datagridview

I am using a BindingList as a datasource with a DataGridView.  The issue is that when the user selects any cell in the new row, a placeholder object is created in the BindingList and the values show up as 0s in the new row. When the user navigates away from the new row, the values in the new row disappear and the placeholder object is removed from the BindingList.  This is very distracting and confusing.  Also, there is the problem when you leave the cursor in the new row, the placeholder object is still in the list.  So, when I serialize the list, the placeholder object will persist also.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior or to mask it? I am thinking of turning all my property members types to nullable, so it doesn't "show" anything and I can filter out the last list item if it contains nulls before serializing it.

Note:  I am not trying to edit anything and I am just navigating to the new row.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property to false?